# Customizing the Debug level

Tags: debug

Can i customize the debug levels to match my needs instead of having all the levels from Info to Finest? I don't need all these levels. All i need is 2-3 levels to which I want to confine my data depending on the priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own Debug Levels by following these steps:

1. Setup > Logs > Debug Level
2. Click the New button
3. Name your new Debug Level (Woohoo!)
4. Select your level of Debug for each Category

[image]

After you have created your new debug level you can apply it to a user trace flag.